# how do I put this schematic into a breadboard?

Tags: digital-logic, schematics

I need for a project to make an electrical dice in a PCB, but first I need to prove the design in a breadboard, I really don't understand all the schematic, so I need a huge help on this. Specifically, I don't know where is the trimmer, and how to plug the PAL22V10.

The schematic:

[image]

(Click the image for the full size version)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like Arik says the PAL22V10 is a logic IC, which you have to program like an EEPROM. You'll have to write a program which represents the internal logic in some awkward HDL (Hardware Description Language), which you then program into the device using a hardware programmer. You don't want to do all that.

If you were attracted by the simplicity of the schematic you may look out for a microcontroller solution. The PAL22V10 is an old beast, and not so user-friendly, but today's microcontrollers are very easy to write a program for *and* to get that program into the device.
[Example project](http://tuxgraphics.org/electronics/200708/electronic-dice.shtml).

If you want to try it without microcontroller, but with commonly available components, then there's [this electronic die project](http://www.tech.plym.ac.uk/dcee/staff/paulfilmore/teaching/undrgrad/DiceProject00.pdf).

Comment: PAL ~ PROM;  GAL ~ EEPROM

Answer (score 7):

The PAL22V10 is a programmable logic chip. When you buy these, they are empty.

The schematics alone will therefore not help you. They do not show how the logic chip needs to be programmed for the desired function.

If you are not familiar with programmable logic chips I suggest you look for a different schematic. It will be easier to implement most logic functions with discrete logic devices rather than programmable chips. They only add an additional layer of complexity. They are normally used when manufacturers want to save space on their PCB.